# Problems while Copying data into pendrive/CD/DVD and locking issues

Tags: partitioning, nautilus, usb-drive, copy

I've noticed couple of Problems have been observed while using the Ubuntu 16 editions.

1. All Folders have a lock icons on it.(Many times installation is not proper)
2. Data from the system is not able to copy into external drives as Pen Drives(Every time while plugging an pen drive it show error as partition is read only cannot Copy)

I have tried to resolve problems using `chmod` command(to remove lock) and nautilus (for resolving copy problem). Still I'm not able to figure out Possible Solution. Can anyone Help.?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I got rid of the two ^_^

Comment: Because of formatting issuse

Comment: what is the ownership on the folders with `lock` icons on it?